# Kinect on OSX Lion 10.7

Tags: kinect, macos, macos-mountain-lion, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What is the best way to get Kinect working on OSX Lion with ROS Diamondback? I am holding off on Electric until it is ready for OSX.

I tried compiling the unstable openni driver from OpenNI.org, but none of the sample programs worked. Has anyone else gotten Kinect to work?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11040/kinect-on-osx-lion-10.7/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2011-08-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2011-11-25**:
I still can't make this work ... even using the precompiled drivers from PCL, the programs don't work. The best option is to use libfreenect (http://openkinect.org -- they even have a homebrew formula). There are already a couple packages for it and it really isn't hard to write something yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already answered my question in the comment ... use libfreenect.

**Update: 5 May 2012**

I have updated the old [libfreenect kinect](https://github.com/walchko/kinect) package and it appears to be working. I am trying to get [pcl_ros](http://answers.ros.org/question/33335/error-compiling-pcl_ros-on-osx-fuerte) to work now on OSX.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1